# Is it possible to set some environment variables for all projects in a folder in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a set of projects in a folder in Jenkins 2.32.1 and I want them all (in this folder) to have a couple of environment variables loaded when the build runs. Is this possible? I have the folders plugin and had a look but didn't see anywhere to configure that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. From Manage Jenkins, find *Global properties*. Under there is a checkbox for *Environment variables*. Select *List of key-value pairs* and add yours.

...according to CloudBees, that feature is available in the "non-free" Folders-Plus version. go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-user-guide‌​/…

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but that configures the variables for the entire server. I'm after something that does exactly that but at a folder level.

Comment: ...according to CloudBees, that feature is available in the "non-free" Folders-Plus version. https://go.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-documentation/cje-user-guide/index.html#folder

Comment: do you want to add that as your answer and I'll accept?

Comment: @MarkAllison asked specifically about setting the properties for all jobs inside a folder. This would set them for all jobs across all folders. Ergo, this is not the right answer. The answer below by Serge S is the correct one.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it's possible, see https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Folder+Properties+Plugin

> A Jenkins plugin which allows users with config permission to define
>   properties for a folder which can then be used by any jobs contained
>   within it or any of its sub-folders.

Comment: @MarkAllison asked specifically about folder properties, so this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Environment variables and properties are not the same thing. This is not the answer, nor is the accepted answer.